# OK, why is my iPhone 5 now a super electromagnet?

Tags: iphone

Please don't tell me it is the speaker magnet. I assure you it is not. Have had it a couple years, and this just started a few months ago. It will pick up nuts and bolts, I can toss it up against my fridge, it will stick. Same on my gunsafe, toolbox, car, and anything else metallic. This is not normal, and not healthy. So what is the answer? Anyone?

Comment: We're not a good place for health effects of magnetic fields - maybe at https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-fields - If instead,  you're wondering how you would measure magnetic field or if it might affect the hardware, please edit the post to clearly explain a little how you are measuring "super magnet" or if that's what you seek as a user of the iPhone. Once you've edited the post, the hold will be reviewed by experienced site members for reopening this to more answers than the one here now.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said *Please don't tell me it is the speaker magnet*, but I have opened a number of iPhone 5 phones and this is the only magnetic part within the whole iPhone 5 - so it **can't** be anything else.

And when you say *I assure you it is not* the speaker magnet, how do you know? What evidence do you have?

The reality is it can't be anything else. If you check this [iPhone 5 teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+5+Teardown/10525) you'll see everything that's inside your iPhone 5. While some parts are magnetic in the sense that they will *stick* to a magnet, the only magnetic source is the speaker magnet.

Also, because the iPhone comes with a compass, it has been very carefully designed so that any magnetic fields do not interfere with that. In other words, Apple hasn't placed any unnecessary *magnets* in the phone except for the speaker magnet (which can't be avoided).

Finally, while I'm no medical expert, the concern around mobile phones has always been around the electrical signals they require to operate, not about magnets. If you're concerned you can use an appropriate case (if you haven't already got one) and/or use a bluetooth earpiece/headset for calls.